# Is it a good idea to always mark non-virtual methods with final?

Tags: c++, c++11

I really don't see a point in overriding non-virtual methods, since it creates a whole range of potential bugs where sometimes original base and sometimes child's method is called.

Following that logic, making a method always come to a simple rule:
Can this method be ever overridden? If Yes - mark it `virtual`, if no - mark it `final`.

To me it all sounds well, but I'm wondering if I'm really missing something important and why no one else follows that simple rule?

Comment: A) you can't override non-virtual member functions. B) did you try marking a non-virtual member function as `final`?

Comment: You can't override non-virtual methods, only hide them, and you can't use `final` on non-virtual methods.

Comment: Clang gives an error on this `error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'final'`, so I would go with 'no'.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Sorry for a dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program that contains a non-virtual function, and which has every non-virtual function as `final` and follows the C++ standard, is guaranteed to be completely bug free.

So there is that.

Still: I advise against it.

It also does not exist.  The `final` positional keyword can only be applied to `virtual` functions.  The first paragraph is known as a vacuous satisfaction joke: every example of a non-existing thing has every property, because there are no examples.

Creating a non-overriding `virtual final` function would be confusing to people reading it.  It would prevent a descendent type from declaring a method with identical signature: but it would not prevent a slightly different signature, so it is mostly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, each member function that you write must be either explicitly designed to be overridden, or be invariant. However, virtuality is something that you must add at the very top of the hierarchy; you cannot add it in the middle. However, you can "take away" virtuality from this class down by marking a virtual member function `final`.

Since `final` can be applied only to virtual member functions, we will not consider non-virtual member functions in the discussion below.

A common practice is to design a class for direct use or for inheritance, but not both, i.e. when you do not instantiate classes in the middle of inheritance hierarchy, and you do not inherit from "leaf" classes of the hierarchy. This practice has been popularized by the [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X) book, item 33. If you follow this practice, you should mark `final` all virtual functions of leaf classes to let the compiler help you find all violations of the rule.

Comment: `struct base { int x(){ return 1; }}; struct mid:base {virtual int x(){ return 2; }}; struct bottom:mid{virtual int x(){ return 3; }};` is not a valid program?  (It is a poor program, but should not is not cannot)